# Netty Camel add custom handlers to pipeline

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, netty

This is a little loaded question, but hope someone can help me with this.

I have a Camel Netty RouteBuilder I create several different beans of, where each bean is listening to a specific port. Just setting it up and letting Netty do all the configuration works okayish, but I want to add my own handlers because I need to keep count of how many threads are being used by each route and threads used in total.

I have tried extending ServerInitializerFactory, which lets me customize the pipeline with my own handlers etc. I need for example one shareable handler with a static counter for closing connections if it's bigger than max threads in a shared thread pool, and a handler that's identical but counting for each receiver if I want to limit how many threads a single route can use (only add one threadhandler here).

```
public class NettyServerInitializerFactory extends ServerInitializerFactory {
    private final NettyConsumer consumer;
    private final int throttleLimit;
    private final int maxThreads;

    public NettyServerInitializerFactory(int throttleLimit, int maxThreads, NettyConsumer consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.throttleLimit = throttleLimit;
        this.maxThreads = maxThreads;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        ChannelHandler encoder = consumer.getConfiguration().getEncoder();
        ChannelHandler decoder = consumer.getConfiguration().getDecoder();

        // use the factory to create a new instance of the handlers as they are not shareable
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", ((ChannelHandlerFactory)encoder).newChannelHandler());
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", ((ChannelHandlerFactory)decoder).newChannelHandler());

        // add default handler and thread handler
        pipeline.addLast("nettyHandler", new ServerChannelHandler(consumer));
        pipeline.addLast("receiverThreadHandler", new ReceiverThreadHandler(throttleLimit));
        pipeline.addLast("poolThreadHandler", new PoolThreadHandler(maxThreads));
    }

    @Override
    public ServerInitializerFactory createPipelineFactory(NettyConsumer nettyConsumer) {
        return new NettyServerInitializerFactory(throttleLimit, nettyConsumer);
    }
}
```

And I add this to the registry

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    NettyServerInitializerFactory factory = new NettyServerInitializerFactory(throttleLimit, maxThreads, null);
    // Weird way of adding to registry, but only way I've made it work
    NettyServerPipelineFactory pipelineFactory = new NettyServerPipelineFactory(null);
    final CamelContext camelContext = getContext();
    final SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry();
    final CompositeRegistry compositeRegistry = new CompositeRegistry();
    compositeRegistry.addRegistry(camelContext.getRegistry());
    compositeRegistry.addRegistry(registry);
    ((DefaultCamelContext) camelContext).setRegistry(compositeRegistry);
    registry.put("spf", factory);

    from("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:" + port + "?serverInitializerFactory=#spf&sync=true&exceptionHandler=#loggingFilterNetty&workerGroup=#nettyWorkerThreadPool&disconnect=true")
        // exception handling and processing
        .inOut(requestUri)
}
```

These handlers would ideally be able to take parameters, but I can't get this to work as the NettyServerInitalizerFactory overwrites all member variables with the first one's being made when setting the consumer, which I assume is what is meant by this in the docs: `Implementators must support creating a new instance of this factory which is associated to the given NettyConsumer using the createPipelineFactory(NettyConsumer) method.`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked out the [tests of camel-netty](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/main/components/camel-netty/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/netty)? And check out the Camel annotation `@BindToRegistry("beanname")`. It is the `@Bean` of Camel

Comment: @burki Will take a look, thanks!